# Some UNO rules questions

Tags: uno

I just have some questions about the rules of UNO, since me and my cousins are relatively new to it.

1. Assuming we're only 2 players left, and I already placed my last card *(Example, a +4 Card)*, but then my opponent also played a +4 on top of my +4 card, is it invalid? Or do I get to draw 8 cards?
2. When I play a +4 card, can I immediately place another card on it? *(Example, I played a +4, then called out YELLOW, then placed a yellow "5" on top of the +4 without shifting my turn)*
3. Also the same question as #2, but if I get to place a "Skip/Stop" card on top of my +4, will that pass the +4 effect to the next player? *(Example, I placed a +4 then a skip on top of it. The +4 is dedicated to Player B. By putting a stop, the +4 gets passed to Player C instead.)*

Comment: Note that playing an "action" card (+2, Skip, +4, etc) on top of another "action" card to counter it or pass it along is a house rule and not part of the standard ruleset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a great place to read the rules yourself.
From mattel.com: https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf

Now to your questions, which has been partly answered by L_Church:
(even though not completely correct, since you are not allowed to "stack" a draw card — instead of drawing cards from the pile yourself):

1. **Yes it's invalid**. It's not allowed by the next player (opponent) to play +4 card on top of a +4 card, instead the next player must draw 4 cards from the pile.

   If you have played your last card you have won, no matter what happens next.

   *But even if that wasn't true, it's not valid to play a +4 card on top of a +4 card, instead it's MANDATORY for that player to DRAW 4 cards from the pile and then it's the next player's turn (who then can play another +4 card or any other card).*

   Anything else is just house rules...

> **Wild Draw 4 Card - This card allows you to call the next color played and REQUIRES the next player to pick 4 cards from the DRAW pile and FORFEIT his/her turn.**

2. **No**. Unless it's a 2 player game, then you can do it, since it's your turn again *(but your opponent still must draw 4 cards)*.

   *If it's a 2 player game or only 2 players left, then if you play a Wild Draw 4 / Draw 2 / Reverse / Skip Card it's okay to play another card immediately after you played the first card - since it's actually your turn again.*

   *If you are more than 2 players, then you are not allowed to play another card - since it's not your turn.*

> **Rules for Two Players - The following special rules apply to two-player UNO.**
> **1. Playing a Reverse card works like playing a Skip card. By playing the Reverse card, you may immediately play another card.**
> **2. By playing a Skip card, you may immediately play another card.**
> **3. After playing a Draw 2 card or a Wild Draw 4 card, your opponent draws the number of cards indicated, and play is back to you.**

3. **No**, you are not allowed to play 2 card in the same turn.

Answer (score 2):

1. A players hand must be empty to win a round. Since you've emptied your hand before your opponent you would win the round. Their play would be invalid since the round is over.
2. Playing a +draw card counts as having you play a normal card. In a 2 player game this will just result in having your turn again anyway. In a 4 player game you cannot play 2 cards like this in one turn. It would move to the next players turn in which they will have to draw or chain a +draw card
3. Same as #2, you cannot play 2 cards in one turn

Comment: Stacking (chaining) a +Draw card is a house rule and not allowed in the normal rules.

Comment: house but extremely common to the point where 1 in a million game hosts will not apply it

Comment: weird world you live in ^^